How to use DROP DEFAULT in MySQL 8?
I'm using MySQL: Server version: 8.0.36 Homebrew
I'm trying to remove the default value of a column (currently set to 0), and it's erroring:
ALTER TABLE comments ALTER COLUMN commentable_id integer DROP DEFAULT;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'integer DROP DEFAULT' at line 1

The above is the syntax i've seen everywhere according to a google search.  I also tried this which i saw on the O'Reilly site: (note no 'COLUMN')
ALTER TABLE comments ALTER commentable_id integer DROP DEFAULT;

but that didn't work either.
If I set a default of null, then it worked:
ALTER TABLE comments MODIFY COLUMN commentable_id integer DEFAULT null;

and that is effectively the same, since my database's "default default" is null anyway.
But, i'd still like to know why the first command didn't work.  Is it a change in V8 perhaps?

Not sure what part of the O'Reilly site you found yourself on, but it's either outdated, a pretty glaring typo, or reference for a different DBMS than MySQL.

You have it almost right, but you can't use the column type, so it is just
alter table comments 
  alter column commentable_id drop default;


To add, modifying the datatype would require a syntax incompatible with this one (using MODIFY instead of ALTER [COLUMN], i.e.: ALTER TABLE comments MODIFY commentable_id integer). You'll necessarily need to perform these alterations in two separate queries. See the docs

@esqew Thanks - i wasn't trying to alter the datatype.  I must have been unlucky with what I googled, the first one that I looked at (https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-remove-a-default-value-to-a-column-in-mysql) had the datatype, like in my question, and then I didn't notice that the second and third things i looked at didn't have that.

I would prefer using
ALTER TABLE comments MODIFY commentable_id integer

instead of
ALTER TABLE comments ALTER COLUMN commentable_id DROP DEFAULT;

When using the first method the table would have the following structure
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL, ##### I added id for demonstration purposes
  `commentable_id` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Using the second method,
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `commentable_id` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


If I insert some data only on id column.
For example
INSERT INTO comments SET id = 2;

With the first method I would have
id  commentable_id
 1      null

with the second one an error will be thrown ,

Field 'commentable_id' doesn't have a default value

See example

hmm so it's better to have a default of null than to not have a default?  Strangely, when I do this ALTER TABLE comments ALTER COLUMN commentable_id DROP DEFAULT; the column is still showing NULL as the default, so maybe my version of MySQL doesn't actually remove the default but rather just sets it to null.  Or, maybe it sets to to the 'default default' set in the db config.

@MaxWilliams hmm so it's better to have a default of null than to not have a default?, yes . If you have a running application with queries which during the inserts skips commentable_id column, from now on if you remove the default with the first method you will be having errors. IMO if you do not want a default in a column,  default null would be better
